# watershed java implementation using opencv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I am trying to implement watershed algorithm with markers in java, found a example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html),
the code is in c++, i tried hard to convert it in java code but failed. Is there anyone who have already done it before? please help!
I stuck at this function (`cv2.connectedComponents()`) because can't find it in [java doc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/).

Comment: The requested Url of the example is offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) to your project, it is an **OpenCV wrapper** for Java. In JavaCV the watershed algorithm is provided by `cvWatershed()`:

```
public static native void cvWatershed(CvArr image, CvArr markers);
```

You might find this thread interesting: [Setting-up javaCV on NetBeans and Eclipse](http://shashindrasri.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/setting-up-javacv-on-netbeans-and.html).

Comment: Why do you need to install Install Microsoft Visual C++?